# Confused about readlink /usr/lib/libpcre.so

Tags: linux

I am following

```
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/pcre.html
```

to install pcrc (OS: CentOS 6.6).

I am confused about this line

```
ln -sfv ../../lib/$(readlink /usr/lib/libpcre.so) /usr/lib/libpcre.so
```

I know it is creating a soft link but not sure why it needs readlink and why 
it is ../../lib instead of /lib?

Hope it is clear. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with that.

These are generic instructions and they assume a non-CentOS/fedora distro.  In CentOS/fedora, /lib is a symlink to /usr/lib (and /lib64 is a symlink to /usr/lib64).  So, the instructions won't work.

On other distros, /lib and /usr/lib are distinct directories.  The command is trying to create a symlink from /usr/lib to /lib, such that:

/usr/lib/libpcre.so --> /lib/libpcre.so
And, /lib/libcpre.so is the real file.

On CentOS/fedora, this would create a symlink cycle:

/usr/lib/libpcre.so --> /usr/lib/libpcre.so

Unless you have a specific reason not to, just do "yum install pcre" and let the distro install handle it.  You may also want the development package:  "yum install pcre-devel"

Also, note that the instructions are for a 32 bit system.  If yours is 64 bit, then we're talking about /lib64 and /usr/lib64.  If your system is 64 bit, but you want to create 32 bit apps, you'll need "yum install pcre.i686"

IMO, in the instructions, using "&&" is "getting cute" and makes me distrust them a bit (e.g. ./configure -blah && make) is technically correct, but it's usually better to do these as separate steps:
- ./configure -blah
- check for errors
- make
- check for errors

The reason that it's relative (using ../..) is so that you could install under /usr/local or other (e.g /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/usr/lib)

Comment: No, it won't create a cycle, unless libpcre.so was already a symlink to itself (which is unlikely). Supposing that the state before was /usr/lib/libpcre.so -> libpcre.so.3, the state after will be /usr/lib/libpcre.so -> ../../lib/libpcre.so.3. If /lib happens to be a symlink to /usr/lib (which is horribly un-FHS) the new target will actually be the same file it was before, otherwise it will be a similarly-named file in /lib. Either way, it's not creating a cycle.